# Launch JNLP file in MS Edge

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp, execution, launch, microsoft-edge

I have a ASP.NET site which offers JNLP files for starting Java Web Start applications. I've set them as `href`s in `<a>` tags to download them. The behaviour I get from different browsers varies:

- IE11: Auto launch
- Firefox (45): Auto launch
- Chrome (48): Manual launch from the download bar
- Edge: Manual launch from the download bar

Chrome is Chrome and I've pretty much given up hope on that, but can Edge be set to launch JNLP files instead of offering the "Open/Show downloads" bar?

Comment: Please see if visiting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/NotepadJWSProject/Notepad.jnlp in your MS Edge auto launches the notepad application

Comment: @JaganathanNanthakumar It does not depend on the content of the JNLP file, Edge simply won't start that file unless you tell it to (or some other means I hope exist). I did try your link though, no luck.

Comment: Clicking that link should auto launch the notepad application if jnlp files are properly associated with the Java Web Start application. It auto launches in both IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome and Edge like you've mentioned.

Comment: @JaganathanNanthakumar Yes. And that's my problem.